# Understanding the probability of a double-six if i roll two dice

Tags: math, statistics, probability

The probability of a double-six in one throw of two die is 1/36 or 0.028.

If I threw a pair of die a hundred times would 3 (0.028 * 100) be

1. The amount of times (3) I would get a double-six

OR

2. The probability (3%) of getting a double-six on all throws.

I have a feeling the correct answer is number 1, because intuitively the chance of getting a double six every time on a hundred throws seems to be a lot lower than 3%.

Please explain, as simply as you can, which is the correct understanding and why.

Comment: Language? Framework? OS? Network? DNS? Console? ...?

Comment: R language for windows.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question of programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability / mathematics, not programming or coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probablity of **not** having double six in one throw (all but one outcome divided by all outcomes):

```
  35/36
```

The probability of **not** having double six in N throws

```
(35/36)**N  /* where ** is raising into N-th power */
```

The probability of having **at least one** double six in N throws

```
P(N) = 1 - (35/36)**N
```

if `N == 100` we have

```
P(100) == 0.94022021...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is nearly 1., but with a twist in the interpretation. 2.8 is the average number of double sixes if you were to perform a series of experiments with 100 throws each. The correct answer for 2. was given by Dmitry.

Please ask math-oriented questions in the math forum math.stackexchange.